# Python: Codecademy PygLatin Translator error

Tags: python

Python 2.7

I was writing code for the PygLatin Translator.
Here's my code:

```
print"Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original=raw_input("Enter a word to translate. Any word.") #Takes an input
if not original=="" or original==" " and original.isalpha()==True: #Checks that 'original' is not an empty text field and also is not a number.
    print original #If both conditions are true then prints 'original'
else: #If both conditions don't come out true then prints an error.
    print"Either the field is empty or your entry was a number."
```

If I give 123 as input, it still prints 123, even though it is a number. It is supposed to execute the else block if the input contains numbers. What's the problem with my code? Please explain in simple words as I am only a Python beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boolean logic is incorrect; the if statement executes as:

```
(not original=="") or (original==" " and original.isalpha()==True)
```

because `or` has a lower precedence than `and` (see the [documented precedence order](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)).

Because your string is not empty, `not original==""` is `True`, and the second part of the expression isn't even evaluated anymore.

The test can be simplified and made correct with:

```
if original.strip().isalpha():
```

because `str.isalpha()` never is True for empty strings. In the above expression, [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes all whitespace from the start and the end of the string, leaving an empty string if there was *only* whitespace in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing your input statement, your input statement is original so if you want to print something else replace original in the if statement with what you want to print